# Как настроить выбор файла для компиляции?

Tags: c++, atmel-studio

В Microchip Studio (бывшая Atmel Studio) в проекте на c++ есть файл `drv.cpp` с хедером и его полная копия `drv_test.cpp` с заглушками для тестирования проекта. Оба файла лежат в проекте, и их функции вызываются из `main.cpp`

Конструкция в файле `main.cpp`

```
#ifdef TEST
    #include drv_test.h
#else
    #include drv.h
#endif
```

не помогает. Компилятор компилит оба файла и ругается на функции с одинаковыми именами. Приходится исключать файл `drv.cpp` из проекта, чтоб протестировать проект.

Вопрос - как-то можно в проекте настроить выбор файла для компиляции, не исключая его из проекта?

Comment: Можете все содержимое cpp-шника засунуть под #ifdef

Comment: @gbg, можно, но не хочу редактировать оригинальный файл по своим соображениям. Наверняка есть какая-то директива в настройках проекта, которая реализовать мой вопрос

Comment: Если они все еще используют GNU Toolchain, можете наделать условий в Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На файле правой кнопокй - properties - build action - none.

Так файл не будет компилироваться в текущей конфигурации.

Добавить несколько конфигураций (для тестов, отладки, релиза и т.д.)  Build - Configuration manager